# OCaml: Simplest way to merge 2 lists

Tags: ocaml

Example: merge [o;d] [l;n] returns [o;l;d;n]

```
let rec merge (x::t1) (y::t2) = 
     x::y::merge t1 t2;;
```

this gives Exception: Match_failure ("//toplevel//", 1, 14)

after merge [o;d] [l;n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `merge` to take 3 arguments (`zip` and two lists), but your recursive call supplies only 2 arguments to `merge`.

**Update**

OK, the fixed up code now has the problem that it doesn't handle the cases where either of the lists is empty. Because of the recursive call this is guaranteed to fail eventually for every input. (I.e., every call will eventually recurse down to the case where one of the lists is empty.)

You should use a `match` statement to handle the different cases: empty `t1`, empty `t2`, and the case you have now (both `t1` and `t2` nonempty).

Answer (score 0):

you might miss two simple cases and use the wrong syntax of match expression.

`let name = function xx | yy | zz` is a syntax sugar of `let name x = match x with xx | yy | zz`

```
let rec merge a b = match (a,b) with
  | (x::xs), (y::ys) -> x::y::merge xs ys
  | xs,[] -> xs
  | [],ys -> ys;;
```

the syntax sugar version:

```
let rec merge = function 
    | x::xs -> (function y::ys -> x::y::merge xs ys | [] -> x::xs)
    | [] -> function ys -> ys
```

`merge` is a function that takes one argument and returns another function.

Comment: Suggest replacing `function ys -> ys` with `Fun.id`.